# How to add a key to a JSON array value?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am new to Postgres and using version 9.4. I have a query returning a `json` column.
How can I add a *key* to a JSON array *value*?

My query:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t))
from (select DISTINCT ON(city,state)latitudes,longitudes,city,state
      from zips where city ilike 'ORL%'
      order by city,state,ziptype desc
      limit 10) t;
```

The output is like:

```
[{"latitudes": 31.22,"longitudes": -103.91,"city": "Orla","state": "TX"}, ...
```

However, I would like to name it such as:

```
["Locations": [{"latitudes": 31.22,"longitudes": -103.91,"city": "Orla","state": "TX"}, ...
```

Comment: `json_build_object('Locations', array_to_json(array_agg(t)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked

Answer (score 2):

Like [@Abelisto commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607635/how-to-attach-a-name-the-array-json-array-query#comment60812903_36607635), use [`json_build_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) (or `jsonb_build_object()`) to attach a key to your value.
And the simpler [`json_agg(t)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) (or `jsonb_agg(t)`) instead of `array_to_json(array_agg(t))`:

```
SELECT json_build_object('Locations', json_agg(t))
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (city, state)
          latitudes, longitudes, city, state
   FROM   zips
   WHERE  city ILIKE 'ORL%'
   ORDER  by city, state, ziptype DESC
   LIMIT  10
   ) t;
```

Comment: BTW It seems that PostgreSQL 9.4 (mentioned in the Q tags) does not provides some functions for the `jsonb` type unlike the 9.5 version.

Comment: @Abelisto: Yes, `jsonb_agg()` is new in Postgres 9.5. You can substitute with `json_agg(t)::jsonb` in pg 9.4. Either way, the presented query works for pg 9.4 (the OP requested `json`, not `jsonb`).