# Add a Root Key for an Orphan JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to add a Key for the Orphan JSON object

JSON String:

```
string jsonString = "{\"FirstName\":\"Emma\",\"LastName\":\"Watson\"}";
```

Expected JSON String:

```
string jsonString = "{\"PersonName\":{\"FirstName\":\"Emma\",\"LastName\":\"Watson\"}}";
```

I need to add a Key for the above said actual JSON string as like expected JSON using C#.

I tried the following code:

```
string rootKey = "PersonName";
string jsonString = "{\"FirstName\":\"Emma\",\"LastName\":\"Watson\"}";
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
// Need to add a ROOT Key for this jObj...
```

Simillar to the existing question [How to add a key to a JSON array value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607635/how-to-add-a-key-to-a-json-array-value)

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding a property to the object, you're putting the object in another object. Just think of it as a dictionary. Create a "dictionary" and add your object to it. Then you could get the json string back from that object.

```
var jsonString = "{\"FirstName\":\"Emma\",\"LastName\":\"Watson\"}";
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var newObj = new JObject
{
    ["PersonName"] = jsonObj,
};
var newJsonString = newObj.ToString();
```